# Old color attachments being used after resizing window

Tags: c++, rendering, deferred-rendering, vulkan

I have the following deferred rendering setup:

1. The first render pass renders the scene to a fixed size image (2048x2048) from the directional light's point of view to one color attachment as a shadow map.
2. The second render pass renders from the camera's point of view and has four image attachments (1 depth, 3 color) for depth, position, normal and albedo.
3. The last one takes all four color attachments and resolves the deferred rendering. This one outputs to the swap chain image.

In my scene I have a rotating cube.

When the window is resized, the swap chain and the framebuffers are recreated.

After that happened, somehow the **OLD** color attachment images are being used.

(The cube doesn't rotate anymore and resizing shows a rescaled version of the last albedo image.

This is very strange since these image should no longer exist.

I have checked and the images and descriptors I am using are being updated properly.

Has anyone else experienced this pitfall and can point me in the right direction to fix this?